# How can I Find out what BCL types a custom type is using its method?

Tags: c#

If I have a class, eg T1, and I want to know what classes in the BCL it is using, how could I do this?

I came up with this:

```
 T1.GetType().GetMethods().Where(x => x.DeclaringType.Namespace == "System");
```

But this will get all methods in my custom type, but I want to look inside each Method, so I was hoping I could do something like:

T1.GetType().GetMethods().BodyTypesUsed; to check if my method uses a type like Streamwriter.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: I have a list of all the types/methods in the .NET library and I want to see how much of this I have used so I need to drill into all of my codebase and find out what types/methods my class methods call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could call [`MethodBase.GetMethodBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx) - that would let you see the types of the local variables. I don't know whether it would show you any "incidentally used" types though...

(You can use the parameter types as well as the return types too, of course.)

Comment: I did a quick try, and it does not include local variables for anonymous methods defined in a method (which is quite expected, of course).

Comment: I actually just wrote this:  T1.GetType().GetMethods().Where(X => X.GetMethodBody().LocalVariables.Select( X1 => X1.LocalType.Namespace == "System")) ;

Will step in and see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible without parsing IL code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Reflector.NET](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) now from Redgate. It lets you navigate the contents of an assembly and disassemble the IL into C#, VB.NET and other .NET languages.

It also lets you pick a type and analyze it in a number of ways, including the kind of thing you're after.

And it's free.

Comment: How is he going to use Reflector programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the below:

```
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Class1).GetMethod("s1");

           MethodBody mBody = mi.GetMethodBody();
```

This lets me inspect the method body and obviously see what's being used (similar to Jon's suggestion).

Thanks guys.